# Nodejs with socket.io getting error on connection in AWS server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am implementing a chat application using nodejs and socket.

Which is working perfect on localhost but not on live server(AWS). I had install socket, node and express js on server.

```
<script src="http://50.112.30.188/chatDemo/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var socket = io();
          $('form').submit(function(){
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
          });
          socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
          });

 </script>
```

And in index.js file

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
console.log('listening on *:3000');
```

The error i am facing is 
"http://50.112.30.188/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1475061508132-0" not found as this is called continuously after running node from terminal with the cmd: node index.js.

i had also tried by add port in io() but makes no difference. So can any of can help me out from this problem as i am new in nodejs. That will be appricated.

Comment: This has nth to do with PHP... removing flag and adding socket.io and express. :-)

Comment: you are trying to connect from AWS machine or from your local machine

Comment: if trying from local machine please check that rules are set for this particular port or not because you can't connect to any unset port on AWS